# Почему у меня Null не равен Null?

Tags: c#

Посмотрите пожалуйста следующий кусок кода:

```
var left = GetSomeEmptyCollection()?.FirstOrDefault();

var b1 = left == null;  //left в данном случае == null, как на картинке

Debug.WriteLine(b1);    //Но, почему получается, что b1 == false ???
```

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему `b1 == false`???

Comment: Какого типа `left`? Перегружен ли у данного типа оператор сравнения?

Comment: ооо, спасибо! Да, перегружен :)) Теперь знаю где искать ошибку :)))

Comment: Чтобы меньше ванговать - приводите [mcve].

Comment: @nick_n_a, ответы - в ответы.